# Parsing Yaml nested configuration with ruamel.yaml in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, ruamel.yaml

When parsing YAML configuration files with Python package `ruamel.yaml` I need to take in account that nesting can be described in two different styles within the same YAML file:

1. by using new line and indents
2. by using dots (.)

**Simplified example:**

Run [repl.it snippet](https://repl.it/repls/LustrousCapitalAudit)

*logging.yml*

```
# 1. by using new line and indents
logging: 
  file: 
    name: app.log
# 2. by using dots (.)
logging.file.path: /logs
```

*main.py*

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import ruamel.yaml as yaml

with open('logging.yml', 'r') as file:
  data = yaml.safe_load(file)
print(data)
```

*Actual output*:

```
{
  'logging': {
    'file': {
      'name': 'app.log'
    }
  },
  'logging.file.path': '/logs'
}
```

Is it possible to configure the `ruamel.yaml` somehow so I can get the `path` property to be nested within logging->file as described below so I can easily access the properties afterwards? :

```
{
  'logging': {
    'file': {
      'name': 'app.log',
      'path': '/logs'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't see how you can get your **actual** output by using the built-in print on your data, everything should have appeared on one line.

Comment: The pretty print of the actual output was just for readability, not something I care about in the code. Should have mentioned that in the post, sorry for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to configure `ruamel.yaml` in the way you
want. I even consider it a bad idea to try and create a constructor
that would do what you want on the fly during loading, as that e.g. means that you
would need to take into consideration that when parsing the mapping
that is the value for the key `file`, a python dict could already
exists as result of splitting up `logging.file.path`.

I suggest that you post-process your `data`:

```
from pprint import pprint
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
logging: 
  file: 
    name: app.log
logging.file.path: /logs
"""


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for k in list(data.keys()):
    if not '.' in k:
        continue
    keys = k.split('.')
    d = data
    while len(keys) > 1:
        d = d.setdefault(keys.pop(0), {})
    d[keys[0]] = data.pop(k)
pprint(data, width=-1)
```

which gives:

```
{'logging': {'file': {'name': 'app.log',
                      'path': '/logs'}}}
```

If necessary you can do that recursively, in case you have keys with
dots that don't exist at the root level.